# Why do I get "ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')" with values from raw_input

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, python-2.x

I am trying to create a really simple program that will plot a plot a parabola where `v` is velocity, `a` is acceleration and `x` is time. The user will input values for `v` and `a`, then `v` and `a` and `x` will determine `y`.

I attempted to do this with this:

```
x = np.linspace(0., 9., 10)
a = raw_input('Acceleration =')
v = raw_input('Velocity = ')
y = v * x - 0.5 * a * x**2.
```

But, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')

What does this mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [documentation of `raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So what happens is that you try to multiply a string with a float, something like `y="3" * x - 0.5 * "3" *x**2`, which is not defined.

The easiest way to circumvent this is to cast the input string to float first.

```
x = np.linspace(0., 9., 10)
a = float(raw_input('Acceleration ='))
v = float(raw_input('Velocity = '))
y = v * x - 0.5 * a * x**2
```

Mind that if you're using Python 3, you'd need to use `input` instead of `raw_input`,

```
a = float(input('Acceleration ='))
```

Comment: why is that the easiest way?

Comment: Well, for python2 you can use `input` instead of `raw_input` but that hides a bit the origin of the problem. And since `input` evaluates the input, there are all kind of hidden traps, while `float(raw_input())` either works or throws an error.

Comment: so casting to float is the safest way?

Comment: Safe in the sense that it may fail and throw an error, but you will always know why it fails (because you haven't typed in a number). For beginners it's definitely the most understandable way.

Answer (score 11):

I faced this problem recently, change the dtype of x to something specific by doing:

```
x = np.asarray(x, dtype='float64')
```