# Calculate the weighted average using groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, weighted-average

here is the dataframe I'm currently working on :

```
df_weight_0
```

[image]

What I'd like to calculate is the average of the variable "avg_lag" weighted by "tot_SKU" in each product_basket for both SMB and CORP groups.
This means that, taking CORP as an example, I want to calculate something as:

(585,134 * 46.09 + 147,398 * 104.55 + ... + 1,112,941 * 75.73) / (585,134 + 147,398 + ... + 1,112,941)

and the same will need to be done for SMB.

Ideally, I'd like to have this two numbers in the dataframe above in a new column (SMB and CORP rows will have their weighted average repeated according to the two values calculated as shown above).

P.S. I will go deeper on more levels in my analysis so the most general the approach, the better.

Thanks in advance,

Stefano

Comment: Would you include your dataframe as a copyable block of text? `df.to_dict()` or `df.head(18).to_dict()` so we would not be required to manually transcribe the data out of this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should do the trick I think

```
import pandas as pd


def calculator(df, columns):
    weighted_sum = (df[columns[0]]*df[columns[1]]).sum()/df[columns[0]].sum()
    return weighted_sum

cols = ['tot_SKU', 'avg_lag']

Sums = df.groupby('SF_type').apply(lambda x: calculator(x, cols))
df.join(Sums.rename(('sums')), on='SF_type')
```

Edit: Added the requested merge with the old dataframe

Comment: Hey Cider. first of all thanks a lot for the answer. I've adapted the formula to my df and I get  this error. Do you know what's about?

TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')

Edit: I got that maybe, it's because I'm formatting the SKU column BEFORE i get any result instead of doing it in the end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013903/typeerror-ufunc-multiply-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types
Describes your error I think.